# Issue with bundle product price not changed on cart page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, price, bundle

I made custom calculation to change product price on cart page.

Product type is bundle.

I used this observer event to set custom price for bundle product.

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
```

My code to set custom price.

```
 $item->setCustomPrice($final_price);
 $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($final_price);
 $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Issue is that product price is changed, rowtotal is also changed  but grand total and subtotal of cart was not changed. grandtotal and subtotal take bundle product original price not my calculated price.

Bundle product price type is dynamic.

But when I create bundle product price type fixed custom price calculation is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To update the cart via an observer don't forget:

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362702/magento-programatically-update-cart-via-event