# Problem with my observer when customer is Logout

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, customer, event-observer, login

i create my observer for change price at cart page

My config.xml is

```
      <events>
          <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
              <observers>
                 <brain_priceedit_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Brain_Priceedit_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updatePrice</method>
                 </brain_priceedit_model_observer>
             </observers>
          </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      </events>
```

and my Observer.php is

```
public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $obs ) 
 {
    $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $product_id=$item->getProduct_id();
        $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $newprice=$_product->getPrice();
        echo$price=$newprice*10;
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
  }
```

this observer working when customer is log in but when customer not log in it's show error like this

[image]

Comment: cannot understand  customer is logout?

Comment: i mean when customer not log in

Comment: still confusing... please explain in detail

Comment: simply forget it i want to change price at cart page so what to do ?

Comment: How can be cart price and this question related?? @vaibhavahalpara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of you can use event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` to change or update price in cart

here i can just show you some little example

```
In your /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/etc/config.xml:

<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <your_event_name>
                        <class>{{modulename}}/observer</class>
                        <method>updatePrice</method>
                    </your_event_name>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>    
    </frontend>
```

And then create an Observer class at `/app/code/local/namespace/modulename/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
    class namespace_modulename_Model_Observer
    {
        public function updatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
        {
            // Get the quote item
            $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();

            // Set the custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }

    }
```

its just idea, you may know better to how to use observer.

hope this will sure help to you.

Comment: i need code to write in observer

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara, Added updated code you can use it.

Comment: this solution is not working for bundle product

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/issue-with-bundle-product-price-not-changed-on-cart-page use this link, i am sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.There are issue with save function and product id

remove `$quote_item->save();`   and

Change to  `$quote_item->getProductId();` from `$quote_item->getProduct_id();`