# checkout_cart_save_after not working

Tags: product, price

i wrote below code to change product price to custom one

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mour_Customgroup>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mour_Customgroup>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <setadiscountprice>
                    <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>modifyPrice</method>
                </setadiscountprice>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Model/Observer.php

```
    $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
    $product_id=$item->getProductId();
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $newprice=$_product->getPrice()+rand(10,100);

    Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');

    // Set the custom price
    $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
    // Enable super mode on the product.
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

}
```

}

the above code add same amount to all items in cart what if i want to add different prices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `checkout_cart_save_after` you can use this evernt tfor modify price `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

here i have given some example with code with my previous answer

[Problem with my observer when customer is Logout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49906/problem-with-my-observer-when-customer-is-logout/49910#49910)

**Edit**

```
   <?php
class Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs ){
    // Get the quote item

        $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $product_id=$item->getProductId();
        $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $newprice=$_product->getPrice()+rand(10,100);

        Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');

        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    }
}
```

i am sure it will work for you.

Comment: thanks but it adds prooduct original price where have i to chnage?..

Comment: see my update quesntion i did as link you gave

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362702/magento-programatically-update-cart-via-event may help you

Comment: could you please update my code could not figure out
$item->getOriginalPrice() should return product price

Comment: @mour, see my updated answer.. i have used it for discount apply.

Comment: nothing gets added some error i think with your code

Comment: i have just gave u pseudocode, just checkwith detail in core files may help u

Comment: see my update your code add same amount to all items in cart what if i want to add different amount

Comment: @mour,if my answer is really helps you should be accept. so someone can take help of it

Comment: yeah it works but it add same amount to all items in cart any ways i created new question for it see :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50136/custom-donate-module

Answer (score 0):

By listening to an after save event your new price will never be persisted to the database, so whenever the quote item is loaded from the database it will have the original price.

Comment: what to do if i want to show custom price??