# custom donate module

Tags: product, price

i want to add custom donate(like tip) module in addition to product price

suppose Product A (price 100) have text box field 
1:donate with blank value which user have to enter user can insert any value and product price will be donated value + product price

how can i implement this via observer

i tried using "checkout_cart_product_add_after" observer

code of observer.php

```
class Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs ){
    // Get the quote item

        $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $product_id=$item->getProductId();
        $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $newprice=$_product->getPrice()+10;

        Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');

        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    }
}
```

but this code adds same amount to add items in cart

my issue are

1. how to pass value of donate text box to observer
2. add donated value to product price
3. donted value should also show in admin order detail

Answer (score 0):

you can get params value with

**Front controller**

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

I am sure this will get done your work.

Comment: how to 2: add donated value to product price

Comment: you can print all values in observer and see with above function

Comment: now i want to add donated value to product in cart like product price 100 donated value 10 =110 in cart via observer
product b price 20 ,donated value 30=50 in cart